# Problems placing 6 columns inside div correctly with centered buttons

Tags: html, css, button, angular-material, multiple-columns

I am doing a Angular Material Tab to change the different types of customization of my app, and i want to place 6 centered buttons inside that tab, but I am having problems with it, because they don't get centered and when I try to do it, they get placed horizontally.

[Image - My tab and the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uuhh.png)

```css
.ButtonZone{

  display: table;
  width: 100%;


}

.column {

  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;

}


#blue{
  background-color: blue;

}

#yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
#pink{
  background-color: deeppink;
}

#red{
  background-color: red;
}
#green{
  background-color: green;
}

#grey{
   background-color: grey;
}
button{
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="ButtonZone">
<div class="column">
  <button id=blue></button>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <button id=yellow></button>
</div>

  <div class="column">
    <button id=pink></button>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <button id=red></button>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <button id=green></button>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <button id=grey></button>
  </div>


</div>
```

The buttons are place on the left side of each column, but I want them to be placed at the center, but I can't do that. I tried many things, but when I do they get horizontal aligned.

One thing that I noticed is the columns leave that right space (see on image) even with width : 100%.

Can anyone help me or give me some ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align: center; to your column class. Add width: 90% to your ButtonZone with margin: auto; to center the entire group.

```
.ButtonZone {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/wheel58m/pen/pojQpya)

Comment: Thanks man! And about that right space on my image that is with nothing, can you help me with that too? Its sett to 100% but it has that space

Comment: You have 6 columns set to width: 15%. 6 x 15 = 90%. The extra space is the remaining 10%. If you set ButtonZone to a width of 90% with margin: auto the whole group will center. *See updated answer.